# Birthday problem with large $n, d$ values

Tags: probability, probability-theory, birthday

In the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Cast_as_a_collision_problem), the formulas

$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}p(n;d)&={\begin{cases}1-\displaystyle \prod _{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1-{\frac {k}{d}}\right)&n\leq d\\1&n>d\end{cases}}&\approx 1-e^{-{\frac {n(n-1)}{2d}}}&\approx 1-\left({\frac {d-1}{d}}\right)^{\frac {n(n-1)}{2}}\end{aligned}}}$$

work well for $d = 365$ and $n=23$, and gives the usual estimation that if you have 23 people in the same room, the probability to have at least two people born the same day is $\geq 50 \%$.

**Question: what formula is available for $p(n; d)$ with more precise error terms?**

---

Concrete application:

I'm using random **5-alphanumeric-character identifiers** for an inventory of objects.

Example: V4QH7, WYJ9X, LK6H4, etc.

If I have $n = 10,000$ objects, what is the probability that at least 2 objects have the same ID?

Note: the last formula (the one after the one with exponential function above) gives `Error, numeric exception: overflow` in Maple when I take $d=(26+10)^5=60,466,176$ and $n=10,000$.

The formula with exp gives $p \approx 3.8 \%$ but since no error term is given, I don't know if this is accurate.

---

Edit: Mistake: $p \approx 3.8 \%$ was obtained when I took $d=33^6$ (6-alphanumeric characters with a few letters removed for easier identification: I vs 1, etc.). With $d=36^5$, we get $56.3 \%$ probability of having a collision with the exp formula above, which is in accordance with the accepted answer.

Comment: It might be best to write $p(n,d)=1-\frac{d!}{d^n(d-n)!}$, then use Stirling's approximation, which comes with definite (as opposed to asymptotic) upper and lower bounds. You need look no further than the introduction paragraph in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for this idea. Even if an answer has been found, feel free to post this as an answer, it will be useful for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done pretty straightforwardly as follows: we want to upper bound

$$- \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \log \left( 1 - \frac{k}{d} \right)$$

and we can do this by applying an upper bound for $f(x) = - \log \left( 1 - x \right)$. On $x \in [0, a]$, Taylor's theorem with remainder gives that

$$|f(x) - x| \le \frac{f''(\xi)}{2} x^2$$

where $\xi$ maximizes $f''(x)$ for $x \in [0, a]$. We have $f'(x) = \frac{1}{1 - x}$ and $f''(x) = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}$, which is maximized when $x = a$. This gives that

$$- \log (1 - x) \le x + \frac{x^2}{2(1 - a)^2}, x \in [0, a]$$

and setting $a = \frac{n}{d}$ gives

$$- \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \log \left( 1 - \frac{k}{d} \right) \le \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left( \frac{k}{d} + \frac{k^2}{2 (d^2 - n^2)} \right) \le \frac{1}{d} {n \choose 2} + \frac{n^3}{6(d^2 - n^2)}.$$

On the other hand, by convexity we have $-\log (1 - x) \ge x$ which gives a lower bound

$$- \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \log \left( 1 - \frac{k}{d} \right) \ge \frac{1}{d} {n \choose 2}.$$

Exponentiating both of these gives

$$\boxed{ 1 - \exp \left( - \frac{1}{d} {n \choose 2} \right) \le p(n, d) \le 1 - \exp \left( - \frac{1}{d} {n \choose 2} - \frac{n^3}{6(d^2 - n^2)} \right) }.$$

Plugging in $n = 10^4, d = 36^5$ gives

$$\boxed{ 0.5625\color{red}{6} \ldots \le p(n, d) \le 0.5625 \color{red}{8} \ldots }$$

which disagrees with your answer. Heuristically these estimates tell us to expect a non-negligible probability of a collision once $d \approx {n \choose 2}$ (equivalently, once the *expected* number of collisions, which is exactly $\frac{1}{d} {n \choose 2}$ and which is an upper bound on the probability, is approximately $1$), and we have ${n \choose 2} \approx 5 \times 10^7$ and $d \approx 6 \times 10^7$, so if you were given these numbers by someone else that was probably deliberate.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Conclusion: Your post confirms that $1-e^{-n(n-1)/(2d)}$ (as given in Wikipedia) is a lower bound indeed for $p(n, d)$.